# Build vanity urls with variables stored in a different table from the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id, vanity-url

I am trying to build vanity urls with FriendlyId gem for a specific model Teacher to display

```
 www.mysite.com/teachers/{first_name}-{last_name}
```

instead of

```
wwww.mysite.com/teachers/{id}
```

The problem that I encounter is that the information on the {first_name} / {last_name} is stored in the table Contact accessible through User and not in Teacher's one. The relation between the tables is as follows:

```
- Teacher belongs_to :user 
- User has_one :contact
```

I added in my Teacher model:

```
 extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :full_name_to_url, use: :slugged
```

So FriendlyId calls the method full_name_to_url to create the slug:

```
def full_name_to_url
"#{self.user.contact.first_name.downcase.gsub(" ","-")}-#{self.user.contact.last_name.downcase.gsub(" ","-")}"
end
```

I received the following message when trying to apply and save all the changes to the already existing records: `Teacher.find_each(&:save)`

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `contact' for nil:NilClass
```

I guess there is something wrong with my method?

Comment: That means that there's no user for some teachers in your database.

Comment: Indeed!! Damned it was so obvious! You are right! Many thanks!